# how to backup database from sqlexpress

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio, ado.net

Please help me to backup my database from sqlexpress.

Comment: Far too vague a question - if you just want to back it up fire up SQL Server Management Studio Express and that'll do it or will give you the script to allow you to do so by other means. If that's not sufficient then we need to know what additional constraints you're working under

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options that you can use:

Using Sql Management Studio you can simply back up the database through the GUI there.

You can automate backups for SQL Express using a combination of this tool,

[ExpressMaint](http://expressmaint.codeplex.com/)

and by using either user fired SQL Commands, or the sqlcmd command line interface, you can schedule the tasks however you want.

Another tool that I have used before, for doing remote backups

[Sql Backup and FTP](http://sqlbackupandftp.com/)

It's nice because it provides a simple to use GUI for doing local and/or remote backups and scheduling them.

Redgate also provides some options for SQL backup, but I haven't used them before but I'm sure if they are like the rest of their tools they are great.

[Redgate](http://www.red-gate.com)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean as a DBA ? You need SQL Express Advanced Edition which includes a version of Management Studio.

Do you mean as a developer (which would explain the tags) ? Create a SqlConnection and a SqlCommand with the "Backup database" as the command text (see Books online for the exact syntax) and use SqlCommand.ExecuteNoResult (or NoValue, can't remember).

Answer (score 1):

```
backup database MyDatabase to disk='C:\PathToBackup\BackupFileName.bak'
```

Comment: This answer might be useful if I knew where to find 'backup'.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the sqlcmd console app. Check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx) (on the samples sections you will find how to perform a backup using this tool).